# How to setup redis on loopback

Tags: redis, loopbackjs

I tried Redis on my node.js server before, the script looks like this:

```
//...

redisClient = redis.createClient();
redisClient.on("connect", function (err) {
  console.log("redis terkoneksi");
});
redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
  console.log("Redis Error " + err);
});

//...

//redisClient.set(...
//redisClient.get(...
```

At this time I want to try to install the redis loopback using the 'loopback-connector-redis' plugin. I have installed NPM, but I don't know how to use it. I have tried writing like this:

```
var DataSource = require('loopback-datasource-juggler').DataSource;
var ds = new DataSource('redis');

ds = redis.createClient(); //script error (createClient is not function)
ds.on("connect", function (err) {
  console.log("redis terkoneksi");
});
ds.on("error", function (err) {
  console.log("Redis Error " + err);
});
```

there are two questions I have:
1. how to use redis on loopback?
2. How to write correctly so that it can refer to the redis 'set', 'get', etc?

I will receive all the answers and suggestions, thank you.
best regards.

Answer (score 4):

LoopBack provides two flavors of Redis connector.

1. Community-maintained [loopback-connector-redis](https://github.com/strongloop-community/loopback-connector-redis) which is implementing CRUD-like storage API using Redis as the "database".
2. [loopback-connector-kv-redis](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-kv-redis) providing a key-value API that's closer to how Redis is typically used.

Since you are mentioning `set` and `get` commands, my recommendation is to use the KV connector. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-kv-connectors/tree/master/redis.lb3x for a full working example.

(1)
Create a datasource backed by the Redis KV connector.

Example: [server/datasources.json](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-kv-connectors/blob/master/redis.lb3x/server/datasources.json)

```
{
  "db": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 6379,
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "kv-redis"
  }
}
```

(2)
Create a new model to represent the KeyValue data and operations.

Example: [common/models/color.json](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-kv-connectors/blob/80cd07da0c964853bf3e27db9af472f4d4ede4c5/redis.lb3x/common/models/color.json)

```
{
  "name": "Color",
  "base": "KeyValueModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

(3)
Attach the model to the datasource.

Example: [server/model-config.json](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-kv-connectors/blob/80cd07da0c964853bf3e27db9af472f4d4ede4c5/redis.lb3x/server/model-config.json#L16-L20)

```
{
  "Color": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  }
}
```

Now you can access all [KeyValueModel](http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#keyvaluemodel) methods on your model, either via REST API or from JavaScript:

```
const Color = app.models.Color;
await Color.set('my key', 'my value', {/*options*/});
```